# Level 2 or more back button listener in Nav component and drawer - android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

I am using Navigation component from Jetpack + Drawer.
On the schema below when I click the left top arrow on second(blue) or third(red) fragments instead of go back it opens the drawer. The device back button works correctly. What function or part of the code covers the logic of the left-top arrow button?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you called `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(yourNavigationView, findNavController())` on your activity.

I can't comment, so if you did call it, please attach code of your setup :D